# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I am using window XP and has chrome version 49.0.2623.75 because of my project requirement. I am using rest operator as below:

```
this.dict = this.header.reduce((obj, k, i) => ({...obj, [k]: this.class[i] }), {})
```

Above code is working fine in latest version of chrome but throwing error in chrome 49. Please can anyone suggest me how could i make work the same code for chrome 49 as well.

Regards
Isha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post the answer of the above question:
this.header.reduce(function (obj, k, i){obj[k] = this.class[i];return obj;},{})